# Javascript 3D projection, avoid objects rotating around themselves

Tags: javascript, 3d, camera, game-development, projection

I am working with 3D projection in Javascript canvas and I'm encountering an issue with the camera.

(Note that in this scene, the camera is fixed and the world objects move/rotate around the camera.)

When the mouse (set to look around fps style) does circular movements, the objects in the scene appear to rotate around themselves.

This should in theory not be happening since I set the rotation of the Meshes to be around the camera when the mouse moves. Any ideas how I could fix this behaviour ?

When running the program :
Lock/hide the mouse by clicking once into the screen, then its basic FPS controls, WASD to move, QE to go up or down, mouse to look around.

Here is a GIF of the behaviour :

[image: SjCAF.gif]

Here is the code :

```js
//GLOBAL CONSTANTS
const MOVESPEED = 0.5;
const MOUSESPEED = 0.0006;

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
let canvas;
let ctx;
let prevMouseX = 0;
let prevMouseY = 0;


//OBJECTS
let camera = {x: 0, y: 0, z: -30, fov: 60};
let world = [];


//CLASSES
class Tri
{
  constructor(v1,v2,v3,col)
  {
    this.points = [v1, v2, v3];
    this.color = col;
    this.behind = false;
  }

  normal()
  {
    let v1 = this.points[1].sub(this.points[0]);
    let v2 = this.points[2].sub(this.points[0]);

    let n = v1.cross(v2);

    return n.normalize();
  }

  facing()
  {
    let cam = new Vector3(camera.x,camera.y,camera.z);

    let n = this.normal();
    let vc = cam.sub(this.points[0]);
    let d = n.dot(vc);

    if (vc.z >= -9) this.behind = true;
    else this.behind = false;

    return d > 0;
  }

  rotate(ax,ay,center)
  {
    let x = ax * (180 / Math.PI);
    let y = ay * (180 / Math.PI);

    const cosX = Math.cos(x);
    const sinX = Math.sin(x);
    const cosY = Math.cos(y);
    const sinY = Math.sin(y);

    let nt = [];

    this.points.forEach(p =>
    {
      //translate to center
      let point = {x: p.x - center.x, y: p.y - center.y, z: p.z - center.z};

      // Rotate around X-axis
      const y1 = point.y * cosX - point.z * sinX;
      const z1 = point.y * sinX + point.z * cosX;

      // Rotate around Y-axis
      const x2 = point.x * cosY + z1 * sinY;
      const z2 = -point.x * sinY + z1 * cosY;

      nt.push(new Vector3(x2 + center.x, y1 + center.y, z2 + center.z));
    });

    return new Tri(nt[0],nt[1],nt[2],this.color);
  }
}

class Mesh
{
  constructor(tris)
  {
    this.tris = tris;
    world.push(this);
  }

  draw()
  {
    this.tris.forEach(e=>
    {
      if (!e.facing() && !e.behind) draw(e);
    })
  }

  rotate(ax,ay)
  {
    let rtris = [];

    //rotate around Camera
    let cx = camera.x;
    let cy = camera.y;
    let cz = camera.z;

    /* rotate around center of Mesh
    this.tris.forEach(e=>
    {
      cx += (e.points[0].x + e.points[1].x + e.points[2].x);
      cy += (e.points[0].y + e.points[1].y + e.points[2].y);
      cz += (e.points[0].z + e.points[1].z + e.points[2].z);
    })
    cx = cx / (this.tris.length * 3);
    cy = cy / (this.tris.length * 3);
    cz = cz / (this.tris.length * 3);
    */

    let center = {x: cx, y: cy, z: cz};

    this.tris.forEach(e=>
    {
      rtris.push(e.rotate(ax,ay,center));
    })
    this.tris = rtris;
  }
}

class Vector3
{
  constructor(x,y,z)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  add(v)
  {
    return new Vector3(
      this.x + v.x,
      this.y + v.y,
      this.z + v.z
    )
  }

  sub(v)
  {
    return new Vector3(
      this.x - v.x,
      this.y - v.y,
      this.z - v.z
    )
  }

  cross(v)
  {
    return new Vector3(
      this.y * v.z - this.z * v.y,
      this.z * v.x - this.x * v.z,
      this.x * v.y - this.y * v.x,
    )
  }

  dot(v)
  {
    return this.x * v.x + this.y * v.y + this.z * v.z;
  }

  normalize()
  {
    let m = Math.sqrt(this.x ** 2 + this.y ** 2 + this.z ** 2);

      return new Vector3(
        this.x / m,
        this.y / m,
        this.z / m,
      )
  }
}


//FUNCTIONS
function init()
{
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.style.display = 'block';
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.onclick = function()
  {
    canvas.requestPointerLock();
  }

  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}

function project(point)
{
  let d = camera.z - point.z;
  let s = canvas.width / (2 * Math.tan((camera.fov * Math.PI) / 360) * d);
  let nx = canvas.width / 2 - point.x * s;
  let ny = canvas.height / 2 + point.y * s;

  return {x: nx, y: ny};
}

function draw(t)
{
  let pa = project(t.points[0]);
  let pb = project(t.points[1]);
  let pc = project(t.points[2]);
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pa.x, pa.y);
  ctx.lineTo(pb.x, pb.y);
  ctx.lineTo(pc.x, pc.y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = t.color;
  ctx.fill();
}

function mouseDir(e)
{
  let deltaX = e.movementX;
  let deltaY = e.movementY;
  let dir = {x: 0, y: 0};

  if (deltaX > 3) dir.x = 'right';
  if (deltaX < -3) dir.x = 'left';

  if (deltaY > 3) dir.y = 'down';
  if (deltaY < -3) dir.y = 'up';

  return dir;
}

// EVENT LISTENERS
//resize canvas with window
window.addEventListener('resize', e=>
{
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
})

//fps kb movements
window.addEventListener('keydown', e=>
{
  if (e.key == 'w') world.forEach(f=>
  {
    f.tris.forEach(g=>
    {
      g.points.forEach(h=>
      {
        h.z -= MOVESPEED * 2;
      })
    })
  })

  if (e.key == 's') world.forEach(f=>
  {
    f.tris.forEach(g=>
    {
      g.points.forEach(h=>
      {
        h.z += MOVESPEED * 2;
      })
    })
  })

  if (e.key == 'a') world.forEach(f=>
  {
    f.tris.forEach(g=>
    {
      g.points.forEach(h=>
      {
        h.x += MOVESPEED;
      })
    })
  })

  if (e.key == 'd') world.forEach(f=>
  {
    f.tris.forEach(g=>
    {
      g.points.forEach(h=>
      {
        h.x -= MOVESPEED;
      })
    })
  })

  if (e.key == 'q') world.forEach(f=>
  {
    f.tris.forEach(g=>
    {
      g.points.forEach(h=>
      {
        h.y -= MOVESPEED;
      })
    })
  })

  if (e.key == 'e') world.forEach(f=>
  {
    f.tris.forEach(g=>
    {
      g.points.forEach(h=>
      {
        h.y += MOVESPEED;
      })
    })
  })

  if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') camera.fov--;

  if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') camera.fov++;

  if (e.key == 'ArrowLeft')
  {
    world.forEach(e=>
    {
      e.rotate(0,MOUSESPEED);
    })
  }

  if (e.key == 'ArrowRight')
  {
    world.forEach(e=>
    {
      e.rotate(0,-MOUSESPEED);
    })
  }
})

//fps mouse movements
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>
{
  let dir = mouseDir(e);

  world.forEach(e=>
  {
    if (dir.x == 'left') e.rotate(0, MOUSESPEED);
    if (dir.x == 'right') e.rotate(0, -MOUSESPEED);
    if (dir.y == 'up') e.rotate(MOUSESPEED, 0);
    if (dir.y == 'down') e.rotate(-MOUSESPEED, 0);
  })

  prevMouseX = e.clientX;
  prevMouseY = e.clientY;
});


//RUNTIME

init();

// CCwise = front facing / Cwise = back facing
let cube = new Mesh([
  //front face CCW
  new Tri(new Vector3(10,10,0), new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(10,0,0), 'salmon'),
  new Tri(new Vector3(0,10,0), new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(10,10,0), 'salmon'),

  //back face CCW
  new Tri(new Vector3(0,10,10), new Vector3(10,10,10), new Vector3(0,0,10), 'mediumorchid'),
  new Tri(new Vector3(10,0,10), new Vector3(0,0,10), new Vector3(10,10,10), 'mediumorchid'),
  
  //top face CCW
  new Tri(new Vector3(0,10,0), new Vector3(10,10,0), new Vector3(0,10,10), 'gold'),
  new Tri(new Vector3(10,10,10), new Vector3(0,10,10), new Vector3(10,10,0), 'gold'),

  //bottom face CW
  new Tri(new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0,0,10), new Vector3(10,0,0), 'cyan'),
  new Tri(new Vector3(10,0,10), new Vector3(10,0,0), new Vector3(0,0,10), 'cyan'),

  //left face CCW
  new Tri(new Vector3(0,0,0), new Vector3(0,10,0), new Vector3(0,0,10), 'red'),
  new Tri(new Vector3(0,10,10), new Vector3(0,0,10), new Vector3(0,10,0), 'red'),

  //right face CCW
  new Tri(new Vector3(10,0,0), new Vector3(10,0,10), new Vector3(10,10,0), 'blue'),
  new Tri(new Vector3(10,10,10), new Vector3(10,10,0), new Vector3(10,0,10), 'blue'),
]);

cube.draw();

let update = ()=>
{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  cube.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
body, html
{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>3DSCAM</title>
</head>


<body>
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Cheers